# how to make a div appears while a function is running

Tags: javascript

i want my page to display a loader while a function is running.
How can i achieve this?

i have tried

```
function myfunc(){
$("#validate-animation").fadeIn(100);
//my code
$("#validate-animation").fadeOut(100);
```

but the animation does not even show

Comment: What do you do in "my code"? A big loop? A web request? Is it synchronous or asynchrounous?

Comment: If your code in the middle is synchronous then you cannot see any animation because the UI thread is blocked by your very code and won't render any updates!

Comment: ... and if it's asynchronous then `fadeOut` will be called before the asynchronous work begins. The animation will fadeout before it even starts

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir i validate the forms and i also send an ajax request to another page

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir in the "my code" part i validate the forms and i also send an ajax request to another page

Comment: @CherryDT the code in the middle validates the forms and i also send an ajax request to another page

Comment: Put the `fadeOut` in the AJAX success function.

Comment: add some html code as well that you're trying to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the ajax code is asynchronous, the `fadeout` actually happens before the ajax starts even though the statement for `fadeout` happens after the ajax one.

To make sure `fadeout` only starts after ajax finishes, you have to put it in the [`complete`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) callback of `ajax` or in the `done` callback that you can chain to the ajax request:

```
$("#validate-animation").fadeIn(100);                      // start the animation

// form validation

$.ajax({                                                   // make the ajax request
  /* ... */
}).done(function() {                                       // and only when ajax is done
  $("#validate-animation").fadeOut(100);                   // stop the animation
});
```